# Only generate supports between object and bed (for a brain model)

Tags: slicing, slic3r, support-structures

I would like to print a model of my brain (figure 1), it requires supports (figure 2). The supports also get generated between the brain folds/wrinkles of the brain by Slic3r. I only want the supports to be generated between the bed an the object, not within the object itself. I thought of writing a script to edit the g-code, is there an easier way out?

**Figure 1:**
[image: brain g-code slic3r stl]
**Figure 2:**
[image: brain g-code slic3r supports stl]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within Slic3r, there are settings for support, which can be enabled to create support only from the build plate. This would still generate supports under the brain, but not within the hollow sections.

[image: slic3r support settings]

Comment: This worked, I had to install the latest version to get that option (cloned from github)

Comment: You could check meshmixer, the tree supports are pretty neat for complex models. You can edit the auto generated supports and when you are happy with the result it gets embedded in the 3d model.